# Creating a GUI in node

Tags: javascript

I have a script (.js file) which is using node, selenium and webdriverjs to go to a webpage.

Is there any easy way to create a GUI with a text box and button which I can input the URL to go to, rather than it be hard coded in the .js file?

Apologies, I'm a complete noob so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Maybe just serve up a web page where you can type it?

Comment: Thanks. So say I create a regular HTML webpage with a form - where should the form point to / what action should be on the form?